# Tracking all screens using Google Analytics in Ionic 3 project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm in the middle of finalizing an Ionic 3 build and would like to add Google Analytics to it. I added it successfully and can see in GA (real time) that the app is being used however I would like to track all page/screen views. Does anyone know of way to do that?

I'm using the following plugin: https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

Here is the code I am using to initialize GA

```
 initGoogleAnalytics() {
    var trackingId = 'UA-114720506-2';
    if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // for android 
      trackingId = 'UA-114720506-2';
    } else if (/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // for ios
      trackingId = 'UA-114720506-2';
    }
    //platform is injected in the Constructor
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.ga.debugMode();
      this.ga.startTrackerWithId(trackingId).then(()=> {
        console.log("GoogleAnalytics Initialized with ****** : " + trackingId);
        this.ga.trackView('schedule');
        this.ga.trackView('speakerList');
        this.ga.trackView('map');
        this.ga.trackView('social');
        this.ga.trackView('exhibitors');
        this.ga.enableUncaughtExceptionReporting(true)
        .then((_success) => {
          console.log("GoogleAnalytics enableUncaughtExceptionReporting Enabled.");
        }).catch((_error) => {
          console.log("GoogleAnalytics Error enableUncaughtExceptionReporting : " + _error)
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you already have a service where you initialize the google analytics plugin? If that's the case, could you please add it to your question? That way I can use that code and add an answer :)

Comment: @sebaferreras I updated the question to include the code

Comment: OK, so it looks like simply adding it to the app.module.ts file isnt going to be enough. When I initialize it on each page I seem to get better results. I'm still testing though

Answer (score 1):

Essentially adding in the GA Module and initializing with ionViewDidEnter on in every page that I wanted to track did the trick.